# How many $7$-digit numbers can be formed using only numbers $1-5$, each of them appearing at least once?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I've been presented with the problem contained in the title, which comes from a math textbook. I solved it as follows:

Considering, that we can only use digits $1-5$ and we have to form a $7$-digit number, there are $2$ cases of repeating digits:

1. One of the digits appears $3$ times.
2. Two digits appear twice each.

For the first case, the solution is
$$
N_1 = \dbinom{7}{3} * 5 * 4! = \dbinom{7}{3} * 5!
$$
Which means, that first we select $3$ "places" in the $7$-digit number, then select which one of $5$ numbers will populate them, and fill the rest of the spots with $4!$ permutations of the remaining numbers.

For the second case, the solution is
$$
N_2 = \dbinom{7}{2} * \dbinom{5}{2} * \frac{1}{2} * 5 * 4 * 3! = \dbinom{7}{2} * \dbinom{5}{2} * \frac{1}{2} * 5!
$$
First, we choose $2$ spots out of $7$ for the first repeating digit, then another $2$ spots out of the remaining $5$, halve it, since those choices will produce double the amount of equivalent patterns, then choose the first repeating digit out of $5$, the second repeating digit out of remaining $4$ choices and fill the $3$ remaining spots with $3!$ permutations of the other digits.

The final solution will then be
$$
N = N_1 + N_2 = \dbinom{7}{3} * 5! + \dbinom{7}{2} * \dbinom{5}{2} * \frac{1}{2} * 5! = \left( \dbinom{7}{3} + \dbinom{7}{2} * \dbinom{5}{2} * \frac{1}{2} \right) * 5! = 16800
$$

This is the solution that I verified in Python, generating all the $7$-digit numbers and counting how many of them satisfy the constraints (i.e. checking for how many of them, the set of their digits equals $ \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \} $).

```
digits = lambda n: [int(d) for d in str(n)]
predicate = lambda n: set(digits(n)) == set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(sum([ int(predicate(n)) for n in range(1000000, 10000000) ]))
```

However, the textbook, from which the question comes, specifies $6720$ as the correct answer.

Is the textbook answer wrong, or did I miss something?

Comment: The textbook is wrong. A third method; you can partition the seven digits into five unlabled parts in ${7\brace 5}=140$ ways (Stirling number of second kind), then label the parts from $1$ to $5$ in $5!$ ways. Indeed, $140\times 5!=16800$.

Comment: Like the very nice confirmation by @MikeEarnest, I got your same answer with from a slightly different approach.  For $N_2$, I used $\binom{5}{2} \binom{7}{4} \binom{4}{2} 3!$ for choosing 2 of 5 numbers to repeat in 4 of 7 positions and placing those in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways before including the remaining $3!$.

Comment: Thanks you both for those comments!
@MikeEarnest this is the first time I'm hearing about Stirling numbers, how are they calculated?

Comment: @Lisu See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind. The definition section gives a simple summation formula.